# Настройка php-fpm в Cpanel. Как добавить в него mysqli

Tags: php, веб-сервер, unix, настройка, php-fpm

Моя проблема заключается в том что основная версия php 5.2 и изменена быть не может в панели Cpanel.

Я использую php-fm для добавления в проект php 5.6 ea (alt не работает phpinfo() возвращает php5.2 всегда) однако туда не загружается mysqli

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

print_r(get_loaded_extensions());

```
Array ( [0] => Core [1] => date [2] => ereg [3] => libxml [4] => openssl [5] => pcre [6] => sqlite3 [7] => zlib [8] => bz2 [9] => calendar [10] => ctype [11] => curl [12] => hash [13] => filter [14] => ftp [15] => gettext [16] => gmp [17] => SPL [18] => iconv [19] => pcntl [20] => readline [21] => Reflection [22] => session [23] => standard [24] => shmop [25] => SimpleXML [26] => exif [27] => tokenizer [28] => xml [29] => litespeed [30] => mhash )
```

Если php5.6 ea то все грузится

```
Array ( [0] => date [1] => libxml [2] => openssl [3] => pcre [4] => zlib [5] => bz2 [6] => calendar [7] => ctype [8] => curl [9] => hash [10] => filter [11] => ftp [12] => gettext [13] => gmp [14] => session [15] => iconv [16] => mhash [17] => Reflection [18] => standard [19] => shmop [20] => SimpleXML [21] => SPL [22] => exif [23] => tokenizer [24] => xml [25] => litespeed [26] => bcmath [27] => dbase [28] => dom [29] => gd [30] => imagick [31] => imap [32] => json [33] => mbstring [34] => mcrypt [35] => mysql [36] => mysqli [37] => PDO [38] => pdo_mysql [39] => pdo_sqlite [40] => pgsql [41] => posix [42] => pspell [43] => soap [44] => sockets [45] => SQLite [46] => tidy [47] => timezonedb [48] => wddx [49] => xmlreader [50] => xmlrpc [51] => xmlwriter [52] => xsl [53] => zip [54] => ionCube Loader [55] => Zend Optimizer ) PHP5.4+ Required
```

но версия как видно из последней строчки ниже 5.4

Собственно вопрос как добавить через Cpanel модуль в php fpm ???

Answer (score 0):

`apt install php5.6-mysql` через SSH и все

Comment: просили через панель, а вы комманд-лайн способ советуете. Способ правильный, но просили другое.